# Oregon Trail Card Game: What happens when you run out of supply cards?

Tags: the-oregon-trail-card-game

So I was playing with my friends the other night and we ran into an issue: We ran out of supply cards in our hands and then came to a river. By the rules of the card, we had to roll an even number to cross or discard a supply card, but we had no supply cards to discard. After scouring the manual we couldn't find an answer to this scenario. Clearly something bad should be happening to us here, but because we couldn't find a ruling we just decided to call it good and forded the river with no consequences. We assume we probably should have died there, but is there a proper ruling to this that we missed somewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After reaching out to Pressman Toy regarding the ruling I received the following:

> In the Oregon Trail narrative, players throw supplies overboard to help cross the river. But, even though the wagon may become empty and technically it would be easier to float, they are stuck. Players must continue to follow the instructions until someone finally does roll an even number!

So unless you are dealing with a river where players die when rolling a one, nothing bad happens, but you do have to spend a little time rolling.

Answer (score 0):

We just played and ran into the same problem. We assume that we all die because in the computer game, when you run out of supplies....you die.